# How to convert Anko DSL Layouts to XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, anko

On my project Anko-layout was used since it was trending at that time, but after IDE and sdk updates i am unable to preview layouts with Anko support plugin and plugin crashes with more than 90 exceptions one of which is argument mismatch exception. Tried downgrading Android studio and plugin but was of no help and the library seems to have abandoned since there is any update or issue fixes recently.

Is there any way to convert the Anko DSL UI to XML?

Or if there is any hotfix for the problem here are my dependency versions:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'
```

Android Studio version 3.4.2 
Anko support plugin version: 0.10.7-2

Comment: Why are you hiding the exceptions (argument mismatch exception) from us?

Comment: @Zun, i am not hiding them, i am not posting them just because there are many questions raising those exceptions but have not got any help and even on Anko github repo itself there are many issues regarding this problem and there seems to be no response/updates regarding those , so i just want to migrate my Anko layouts to other layout files(to XML or android KTX).

Comment: There is no such layout as "android KTX".
I don't think that there is any way to convert it automatically, probably just find/replace may help, or manually port everything

Comment: You can use [Splitties Views DSL](https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties/tree/master/modules/views-dsl) that has working IDE preview and is AndroidX compatible.
Moving from Anko to it is quite easy. If you have further questions about it, other users and myself are happy to help you in the `#splitties` channel on Kotlin's Slack ([invite here](https://slack.kotl.in)).